# jQuery to submit form on file selection not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I am trying to initiate upload of a file as soon as the user selects the file. The form should disappear replaced by the "Uploading your picture..." message.

So far, all I get is the form being hidden (and message showing), but the upload is not happening. The form is not being submitted. Any ideas why?

This is the JS

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#file_select").change(function(){
        $(this).parents("#upload_form").submit();
        $("#upload_form_div").hide();
        $("#loading").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

and the HTML

```
    <div class="float_left" id="upload_form_div"> 
        <h3>Select a picture for your profile (4 MB max):</h3> 
        <form action="http://example.com/profile/upload_picture" 
            id="upload_form" 
            enctype="multipart/form-data" 
            method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

            <input type="file" name="userfile" 
                   id="file_select" /> 
             <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="upload" /> 

         <button id="submit" type="submit"><img height="24" width="24"
                   alt="Upload" src="images/icons/small/white/bended%20arrow%20right.png"> 
                    <span>Upload</span> 
              </button> 
        </form>

        <form action="http://example.com/profile/remove_picture" 
              method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <button type="submit"><img height="24" width="24" 
             alt="Remove" src="images/icons/small/white/trashcan.png"> 
            <span>Remove</span> 
        </button> 
        </form>
</div> 
  <div id="loading" style="display:none;"> 
         Uploading your picture...
   </div>
```

Comment: I added to my answer below - solved the problem for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/q3J4R/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably has something to do with this part:

```
 <input type="file" name="userfile" 
               value="onchange=&quot;return validateFileExtension(this)&quot;"
               id="file_select" />
```

An input type=file should not have a value= attribute (and even if it did, you shouldn't put javascript in there!)

You also have some javascript in the form:

```
onsubmit="return validateFileExtension(this.userfile)"
```

If the function `validateFileExtension()` returns `false` then the form will not submit.
However, the way you have written the jQuery means that the message will still appear.

---

**EDIT:**

Change the id on your submit button to something other than "submit".

[In the jQuery docs:](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

> Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that conflict with properties of a form, such as submit, length, or method. Name conflicts can cause confusing failures. For a complete list of rules and to check your markup for these problems, see [DOMLint](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/domlint/).

---

HOWEVER:

You should consider @Abdul's solution, since the working submit will take you away from your message.

If you are using CodeIgniter and you don't want to use Ajax, you should consider using the flash functionality to display the message to the user after the form submits.

Comment: thanks @willoller - that was a typo in my CodeIgniter code - but even when I remove that it still doesn't work - any other ideas?

Comment: is validateFileExtension() returning true?

Comment: i removed all validation scripts and it still doesn't submit the form

Comment: @willoller - sure! the HTML on OP has been updated - unfortunately still not working

Comment: thanks @willoller - that simple `id` removal solved the problem, much appreciated you taking the time to help with this

Comment: Just a note for 'Change the id on your submit button to something other than "submit"' The same thing goes for the submit button name

Answer (score 2):

You should think of using [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to submit your form and [jquery validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) to validate your form for file extensions and everything.Jquery form plugin submits your form using ajax. In that way you won't be redirected to form action. Also
if you want you can consider using jquery dialog to display the result.

```
 $("#upload_form").validate({
          rules: {
        MyFile: {
          required: false,
          accept: "jpg|jpeg|png|gif"

        }
      }
    });


  $("#file_select").change(function(){
       ("#upload_form").ajaxSubmit();
        $("#upload_form_div").hide();
        $("#loading").show();
    });
```

Comment: thanks abdul - i'll look into this - i also want to avoid too many jQ plugins at this point even if they're lightweight

Answer (score 0):

Submit form on file selection and validate for CSV file input

```
 $('#file').change($('form').submit());
 $('form').submit(function(){
    if($('#file').val().toLowerCase().indexOf('.csv') != -1){
      $('#spinner').show();
      return true;
    }
    else{
      alert('Invalid File format. Please, upload CSV file')
      return false;
    }
  });
```